# Bake Hemi Lamps in Blender Render Mode

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I was wondering how I can bake my hemi lamps into a texture included in the shadow (Full Render mode). I'm satisfied with my lighting (a few hemis and 1 sun) and I don't want to use any lights when exporting it outside Blender.

I would appreciate any help, guide or workaround. Thanks.